# Mac terminal : trying to add to /etc/shells

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

This one works

```
$ cat /etc/shells
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
```

But this one does not :

```
sudo -s 'echo /usr/local/bin/zsh >> /etc/shells'
/bin/bash: echo /usr/local/bin/zsh >> /etc/shells: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo` takes the string as complete command. You should use a shell to interpret your command like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/zsh >> /etc/shells'
```

This executes `sh` with root privileges, and `sh` interprets the string as a shell command including `>>` as output redirection.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you really need `sudo` for is to open the protected file for writing. You can use the `tee` command to append to the file.

```
echo /usr/local/bin/zsh | sudo tee -a /etc/shells > /dev/null
```